# Polymer doesn't change paper-tab selected attribute

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to make paper-tabs on my application. 
Tab 1 and Page 1 Have to be selected when page load , unfortunately when I'm trying to make  attribute `selected=0` page loads with tab1 active , but I cant change to any other tab , I always see only `Tab 1` with `Page 1` 
Can somebody please tell me what to do to fix that problem ??

Best Regards

I'm writing below what I've tried.

My import extensions

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-pages/core-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
```

And Code:

```
   <paper-tabs selected="0">
            <paper-tab>Tab 1</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Tab 2</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Tab 3</paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>

        <core-pages selected="0">
            <div>Page 1</div>
            <div>Page 2</div>
            <div>Page 3</div>
        </core-pages>
```

Second Option

```
         <paper-tabs selected="{{0}}">
            <paper-tab>Tab 1</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Tab 2</paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>Tab 3</paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>

        <core-pages selected="{{0}}">
            <div>Page 1</div>
            <div>Page 2</div>
            <div>Page 3</div>
        </core-pages>
```

This is method I solved problem:

```
   Polymer('progress-page', {
        ready: function () {
            // make global values available on instance.
            this.selected = 0;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `selected="{{activeTabId}}"` and in JavaScript set default value:   `activeTabId: 0`

Comment: Second ago I fixed problem with
Polymer('progress-page', {
            ready: function () {
                // make global values available on instance.
                this.selected = 0;
            }
 });

Answer (score 1):

You could make a custom element that wraps the tabs with the pages then use the two-way binding `{{selected}}` to automatically keep tabs and pages in sync.

Here is a gist for [easy-paper-tabs](https://gist.github.com/toby-1-kenobi/0070cd2a600bd570f83496e8adf64053)